# Redirect URI missmatch for Google OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications Issue, why redirect_uri = 'postmessage' solves it?

Tags: authorization, google-oauth, google-ads-api

I'm using the auth code flow (https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/how-user-authz-works#when_using_the_auth_code_flow) for Google authorization. I have a frontend developed in React in which I already implemented the Google consent screen, and when the user finishes authorizing the scopes I need, I get a code. I know I have to exchange this code for an access token and a refresh token using my backend. My backend is programmed in Flask, but when I do the request as shown in the docs (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code) I have to pass the "redirect_uri" parameter. I know I have to pass a valid redirect_uri, registered in the Google Console when I created my credentials [(List of my Redirect URIs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyI3m.png), and I'm doing this, but I keep getting the "(redirect_uri_mismatch) Bad Request" error over and over again.

This is my Python function:

```
def get_access_token_from_code(self, code):
    try:
        flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
            client_secrets_file = 'client_secret.json',
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords'],
            redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/oauth/google'
        )
                
        flow.fetch_token(code=code)
        # Store the credentials in the session.
        credentials = flow.credentials
        print({
            'token': credentials.token,
            'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
            'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
            'client_id': credentials.client_id,
            'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
            'scopes': credentials.scopes
        })

        return {
            "message": "Access token obtained successfully",
            "data": {
                "access_token": credentials.token,
                "refresh_token": credentials.refresh_token,
                "token_uri": credentials.token_uri,
                "client_id": credentials.client_id,
                "client_secret": credentials.client_secret,
                "scopes": credentials.scopes
            },
            "error": None
        }, 200

    except Exception as e:
        return {
            "message": "Something went wrong!",
            "error": str(e),
            "data": None
        }, 500
```

However, when I do redirect_uri = 'postmessage' it works! And I get the access and the refresh tokens! I read this option in an old post back in 2012, and I just can't find any documentation on why this solves the issue, and I'm afraid is not a proper solution. Thanks!